# What resolutions are standard for digital device wallpaper designs?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resolution

What seems to be the most popular resolution that wallpaper comes in for desktop wallpaper?
I am a digital artist so I want people to download my wallpaper. What resolution should I offer it in to encourage that?

I'm not just making wallpaper for desktops, I'm also trying to fit it in small devices like smartphones and other devices.

I'm not just focusing on a particular device indeed I want for all device (which has a screen and are wallpaper capable).

Please tell me exact number of wallpaper that I will have to make.

Comment: By "wallpaper" do you mean "the photo used as the background on your computer" or "a pattern or image pasted on the wall in lieu of paint"?

Comment: the photo used as the background on computer

Comment: "[...]I want for all device (which has a screen and are wallpaper capable). [...] exact number of wallpaper that I will have to make." Is the set of all devices, which is huge. ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_resolutions )

Answer (score 15):

320 x 480 is a very [common resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364313/is-there-a-standard-webpage-resolution-for-mobile-phones) for mobile phones.

[Here is a big list of a lot of phones and their resolutions](http://cartoonized.net/cellphone-screen-resolution.php). Maybe it'll help give you an idea of what's out there.

**For desktops**

Full Screen:

- 800 x 600
- 1024 x 768
- 1280 x 960
- 1280 x 1024
- 1600 x 1200

Widescreen:

- 1280 x 720
- 1280 x 800
- 1366 x 768
- 1440 x 900
- 1680 x 1050
- 1920 x 1080
- 1920 x 1200

1024 x 768, 1280 x 1024, 1920 x 1080 are pretty common to the best of my knowledge. But obviously the more resolutions you support, the more compatible your wallpaper becomes -- the drawback is that it requires more work for you.

Comment: 320x480 is good for web, but too small for mobile wallpapers if you are going to be considering iPhone 4's (960x640)

Answer (score 4):

It really depends on screen size most of the wallpaper designer provide there art in different sizes to look better in each screen though you can take a minimum to maximum size variant

Normal wallpaper has resolution of `1024x768` and screen ratio of `4:3`. I assume  More than 70% of users have such monitors.

HD wallpaper have `1366x768` and screen ratio of `16:9`

so if you consider both you can cover the maximum.

- [Display resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_resolution)

See if these links help :

- [Create wallpaper for various display](http://www.ehow.com/how_5981737_create-wallpaper-various-displays.html)
- [Wallpaper Resolution](http://www.ehow.com/how_6793703_create-desktop-wallpaper-resolution.html)

if you google a bit you can get a good amount of information on this.

Comment: "Normal wallpaper has resolution of `1024x768` and screen ratio of `4:3`. More than 70% of users have such monitors" give reference please..

Answer (score 2):

In this case, why not see what other wallpaper designers do?

Google "HD wallpaper" and look at the resolutions for download.
Most I can find are 1280 x 720. This is a pretty standard resolution for HD wallpaper.

Answer (score 2):

deviantArt has a nice list at [What screen resolutions are accepted in the Wallpaper gallery?](http://help.deviantart.com/813/)

> (Resolutions marked in bold are the current most often encountered
>   monitor resolutions)
>
> Standard PC / Mac (4:3): 640x480 800x600 **1024x768** 1152x864 1280x960
>   1344x1008 **1280x1024** 1400x1050 **1600x1200** 2048x1536
>
> Dual/Multi Display: 2960x1050
>
> Widescreen: 960x600 1024x640 **1280x480** 1280x800 1344x840
>   **1440x900** 1600x600 1600x1000 1680x1050 **1920x1200** 2048x768 2304x864 2560x960 2560x1024 2560x1600 3200x1200
>
> iMac Resolutions: 1920x1080 2560x1440

I suggest you to start with something big like 2560x1600, or if you want to support multi-screen set-ups even 2960x1050, and then work it down to other resolutions.

Comment: Link dead now :/

Answer (score 0):

**1920x1080** is *very* common. However, I would provide higher resolutions as well. For instance:

- MacBook displays are **2880x1800**. (Note: this is **16:10**)
- iMac 5K displays are **5120x2880**.

Got any more? Add it here!

Answer (score 0):

As higher resolution displays have become more common since other answers were given here, and also a wider variety of resolutions has become more common, this answer adapts from resolutions available at wallpaperswide.com (which is very comprehensive), including including mobile and multiple monitor (up to 3 monitors wide) configurations.

[EDIT: I at first wrote that I obtained this list from wallpapers.com; that is incorrect.]

For my purposes I also wanted the aspects in this list, so it is in CSV format: width,height,aspect (x:1):

```
width,height,aspect (x:1)
23040,4320,5.33
15360,2880,5.33
11520,2160,5.33
10662,1999,5.33
8640,1620,5.33
7680,1440,5.33
7200,1350,5.33
6144,1152,5.33
5760,1080,5.33
4800,900,5.33
4098,768,5.33
3840,720,5.33
3840,768,5.00
2400,480,5.00
23040,4800,4.80
15360,3200,4.80
11520,2400,4.80
8640,1800,4.80
7680,1600,4.80
5760,1200,4.80
5040,1050,4.80
4320,900,4.80
3840,800,4.80
9000,2000,4.50
8208,1824,4.50
6480,1440,4.50
6000,1333,4.50
5760,1280,4.50
4320,960,4.50
3456,768,4.50
19200,4800,4.00
12288,3072,4.00
9600,2400,4.00
8400,2100,4.00
7680,1920,4.00
6144,1536,4.00
5760,1440,4.00
5040,1260,4.00
4800,1200,4.00
4320,1080,4.00
4200,1050,4.00
3840,960,4.00
3456,864,4.00
3072,768,4.00
15360,4096,3.75
11250,3000,3.75
7680,2048,3.75
3840,1024,3.75
15360,4320,3.55
10240,2880,3.55
7680,2160,3.55
7108,1999,3.55
5760,1620,3.55
5120,1440,3.55
4800,1350,3.55
4096,1152,3.55
3840,1080,3.55
3200,900,3.55
2732,768,3.55
2560,720,3.55
2048,576,3.55
1920,540,3.55
2560,768,3.33
1600,480,3.33
15360,4800,3.20
10240,3200,3.20
7680,2400,3.20
5120,1600,3.20
3840,1200,3.20
3360,1050,3.20
2880,900,3.20
2560,800,3.20
2304,720,3.20
1920,600,3.20
5600,1800,3.11
6000,2000,3.00
5472,1824,3.00
4320,1440,3.00
4000,1333,3.00
3840,1280,3.00
2880,960,3.00
2304,768,3.00
12800,4800,2.66
8192,3072,2.66
6400,2400,2.66
5600,2100,2.66
5120,1920,2.66
4096,1536,2.66
3840,1440,2.66
3360,1260,2.66
3200,1200,2.66
2880,1080,2.66
2800,1050,2.66
2560,960,2.66
2304,864,2.66
2048,768,2.66
1600,600,2.66
10240,4096,2.50
7500,3000,2.50
5120,2048,2.50
2560,1024,2.50
3840,1600,2.40
3440,1440,2.38
5120,2160,2.37
2560,1080,2.37
7680,4320,1.77
5120,2880,1.77
3840,2160,1.77
3554,1999,1.77
2880,1620,1.77
2560,1440,1.77
2400,1350,1.77
2048,1152,1.77
1920,1080,1.77
1600,900,1.77
1366,768,1.77
1334,750,1.77
1280,720,1.77
1136,640,1.77
1024,576,1.77
960,540,1.77
854,480,1.77
640,360,1.77
480,272,1.76
1024,600,1.70
1280,768,1.66
800,480,1.66
400,240,1.66
7680,4800,1.60
5120,3200,1.60
3840,2400,1.60
2880,1800,1.60
2560,1600,1.60
1920,1200,1.60
1680,1050,1.60
1440,900,1.60
1280,800,1.60
1152,720,1.60
960,600,1.60
3000,2000,1.50
2736,1824,1.50
2160,1440,1.50
2000,1333,1.50
1920,1280,1.50
1440,960,1.50
1152,768,1.50
960,640,1.50
480,320,1.50
6400,4800,1.33
4096,3072,1.33
3200,2400,1.33
2800,2100,1.33
2560,1920,1.33
2048,1536,1.33
1920,1440,1.33
1680,1260,1.33
1600,1200,1.33
1440,1080,1.33
1400,1050,1.33
1280,960,1.33
1152,864,1.33
1024,768,1.33
800,600,1.33
640,480,1.33
320,240,1.33
5120,4096,1.25
3750,3000,1.25
2560,2048,1.25
1280,1024,1.25
220,176,1.25
3840,3840,1.00
2732,2732,1.00
2560,2560,1.00
2048,2048,1.00
1280,1280,1.00
1024,1024,1.00
176,220,0.80
600,800,0.75
480,640,0.75
240,320,0.75
2048,2732,0.74
768,1152,0.66
640,960,0.66
320,480,0.66
800,1280,0.62
768,1280,0.60
480,800,0.60
240,400,0.60
2160,3840,0.56
1440,2560,0.56
1080,1920,0.56
720,1280,0.56
540,960,0.56
480,854,0.56
360,640,0.56
272,480,0.56
```